# how to get class name from an interface with multiple implementations in java

Tags: java

I have the following interface

```
Interface fooBar extends Foo {}
```

few classes implementing them

```
class A implements fooBar {}
class B implements fooBar {}
class C implements fooBar {}
```

Now in one of the methods I have the following

```
Foo dummy = someMethod.getIt();
```

I want to know what type dummy is; is it A, B, C
I tried `dummy.getClass().getSimpleName()` and that it did not give any of the three but a random string "AndFunction"

I can do `instanceOf` check for each of A, B, C. That becomes ugly when I have more implementations.

P.S. I have simplified some code which I am trying to debug using debugger in IntelliJ. This is pretty big legacy app with spring beans created and injected during runtime.

Comment: "it did not give any of the three" - What did it give you?

Comment: Instead of instanceof, you should use polymorphism, however, this is hard if you can't refactor the code.

Comment: That name might have been auto-generated (if `someMethod.getIt()` returned a proxy). You can examine the interfaces and/or the superclass of `dummy.getClass()` to figure out what it really is.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko how?

Comment: @brainstorm debug the contents of `dummy.getClass()`